# Child ModalPopupExtender will not center over Parent ModalPopupExtender

Tags: html, asp.net, .net, css, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have an ASP.NET 4.5 App, where I have to use a series of Modal windows.  The first Modal window allows the user to input some data, while the second Modal is used for confirmation purposes.  For some reason, the second Modal window, will not center align.  I've tried the {position: absolute; | RepositionMode="None" | X="0" Y="0" | JS .add_shown } and it does not appear to be working.  Maybe there is problem with my design.  I have tinkered with my CSS, HTML, and Modal Attributes with no success. I definitely need an extra pair of eyes. Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

HTML

```
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="pnlForm" runat="server">
                <ContentTemplate>

                    <br /><br /><br />

                    <asp:Button    ID="ibtSignee" runat="server" Text="Override" />

    <%-- PARENT --%>

                    <asp:Panel ID="pnlEndorse" runat="server" CssClass="endorse-panel" style="display: none;" Height="519px" Width="550px">

                        <asp:Table runat="server" Width="100%">
                            <asp:TableRow>
                                <asp:TableCell      ColumnSpan="5"   Height="90px" Width="100%" />
                            </asp:TableRow>

                            <asp:TableRow>
                                <asp:TableCell  Width="48px"/>

                                <asp:TableCell      ColumnSpan="1"   Height="60px"  HorizontalAlign="Left"      VerticalAlign="Middle">
                                    <asp:ImageButton ID="ibtCancel" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/CustomImage/frm-button-deny-off.png" />
                                </asp:TableCell>

                                <asp:TableCell      ColumnSpan="1"   Height="60px"  HorizontalAlign="Center"    VerticalAlign="Middle" />

                                <asp:TableCell      ColumnSpan="1"   Height="60px"  HorizontalAlign="Right"     VerticalAlign="Middle">
                                    <asp:ImageButton ID="ibtAffirm" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/CustomImage/frm-button-over-off.png" />
                                </asp:TableCell>

                                <asp:TableCell  Width="48px"/>
                            </asp:TableRow>
                        </asp:Table>

    <%-- CHILD --%>

                        <asp:Panel ID="pnlConfirm" runat="server" CssClass="confirm-panel" style="display: none;" Height="203px" Width="550px">

                        </asp:Panel>


                        <asp:Button ID="btnSecret" runat="server" style="display: none;" />


                        <act:ModalPopupExtender ID="mpConfirm" 
                                                PopupControlID="pnlConfirm" 
                                                TargetControlID="btnSecret" 
                                                BackgroundCssClass="modal-circumvent" 
                                                RepositionMode="None"
                                                runat="server">
                        </act:ModalPopupExtender>

    <%-- CHILD --%>

                    </asp:Panel>


                    <asp:Button ID="btnCovert" runat="server" style="display: none;" />

                    <asp:HiddenField ID="hfEndorse" runat="server" Value="false" />


                    <act:ModalPopupExtender ID="mpEndorse" 
                                            PopupControlID="pnlEndorse" 
                                            TargetControlID="btnCovert" 
                                            BackgroundCssClass="modal-circumvent" 
                                            runat="server" >
                    </act:ModalPopupExtender>

    <%-- PARENT --%>

                </ContentTemplate>
                <Triggers>
                </Triggers>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

CSS

```
    html
    {
        overflow: auto; 
    }

    body
    {
        width: 1024px; 
        font-family: "Helvetica Neue", "Lucida Grande", "Segoe UI", Arial, Helvetica, Verdana, Sans-Serif; 
        background: #8B94C4 url('../Images/CustomImage/Sunrise.png') top center no-repeat; 
        text-align: center; 
        font-size: .80em; 
        margin: 0 auto; 
        padding: 0px; 
        clear: both;   
    }

    table
    {
        border-collapse: collapse;
        text-align: center;
    }

    select
    {
        background-color: #E8FAFF;
        border: 1px solid #7BA8B5;
        font-family: "Courier";
    }

    .modal-circumvent
    {
        background-image: url('../Images/CustomImage/endorse-modal.png');
    }

    .endorse-panel
    {
        background-image: url('../Images/CustomImage/AppEndorse.png');
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        font-family: Arial;
        font-size: 9pt;
        color: #336699;
    }

    .confirm-panel
    {
        background-image: url('../Images/CustomImage/AppConfirm.png');
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        font-family: Arial;
        font-size: 9pt;
        color: #336699;
    }
```

Comment: Could you pare down your snippets to include only the CSS and markup that is important to the issue?  A lot of noise in what you've posted so far.

Comment: I cleaned up the snippets a bit.  Is this a little better?

Comment: I've noticed that if I scroll the page, the Child Modal snaps into the correct position.  Not sure why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what the problem was.  I needed to add the following 4 lines to my CSS:

```
    .confirm-panel
    {
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-image: url('../Images/CustomImage/AppConfirm.png');

        margin-right: auto !important;
        margin-left: auto !important;
        right: auto !important;
        left: auto !important;

        font-family: Arial;
        font-size: 9pt;
        color: #336699;
    }
```